# How to load page after array is filled?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have got an angular app, with a component named "detail".

In the detail.component.ts I fetch data from an API and fill it in an array, then filter the array for a certain item and put this item in another array. Here is the shortened code:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
//code
public data: any = []
public item: any = []
//code
constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
getData()
{
const url ='myUrl'
this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {this.data = data; this.item=this.data.find(/*my search*/)})
}
//code
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getData()
  }
```

Then I display the properties of the selected Item with the file "detail.component.html" like this:

```html
<div><span>Name: </span>{{item.name}}</div>
```

This works, the items properties are displayed. 
The problem is, that in the console a lot of ERROR messages appear. They go like this:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

It seems like it is trying to render and display the item.name before the function getData() is done and the array is filled.

Have you any idea how to solve this so that there are no error messages in the console anymore?

Comment: wrap the element containing `*ngFor` with an element containing an `*ngIf`

Comment: with using `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` you cannot load page before filling the array. Using a Resolve is the option to do it. If the page is loaded and your request is sent and your data are not received you vcan use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`

Comment: @dasunse Thanks for the advice - but what exactly is the advantage of a resolve to *ngIf, considering both works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Just
use this

```
<div><span>Name: </span>{{item?.name}}</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div *ngIf="item"><span>Name: </span>{{item.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check before displaying it in the UI.

```
<div *ngIf="item"><span>Name: </span>{{item.name}}</div>
```

And so the `item.name` wont be evaluated until there is value in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is self-explanatory, it is trying to render the view even before the data is available. You can add the defensive condition to resolve this. Something like *ngIf="item && item.name".
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Safe navigation operator `?` like this:

```
<div><span>Name: </span>{{item?.name}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Resolve. [Angular Documentation For Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

[Example Of an Resolve](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resolver-simple-example)